# call a method of the activity in the service which started the service in the first place

Tags: android

I Have an activity `A` that starts a service `B`. Now suppose , i have a method `abc` that is present inside the activity `A` class.

Now somehow i want to call `abc` from the service class which basically stops a specific thread.

Now first solution that came into my mind was to declare that function as `public static` but that isn't possible because that method does use some variables which can't be made static.

Other thought that came into my mind was to pass the current object of the main activity class in the intent while starting the service.

I did try that and i figured out that ain't possible too.

What's the solution to this problem?

P.s: New to android.

Answer (score 1):

> Now somehow i want to call abc from the service class which basically stops a specific thread.

From the service's standpoint, there is no way to know if that activity is still around at this point in time.

> What's the solution to this problem?

Most likely, reorganize your app, such as getting rid of the service or better decoupling it from your UI layer.

Tactically, you can use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, etc.) to have the service publish an event. Your activity can listen for such events and take action, but things will still work if your activity is destroyed while your service continues running.

Comment: its a music player app , so the main activity has the UI while the `musicservice` runs in the background.

Comment: @BOTJr.: The user can press BACK and destroy your activity. The user might rotate the screen, destroying and recreating the activity. In either case, usually, the idea is that the music keeps playing. Hence, the service needs to be decoupled from the UI. The UI tells the service what to play; the service plays it. And that's it. Everything else that the service does has to assume that the UI does not exist.